# Bounced email tracking in java/j2ee

Tags: java, email, jakarta-ee

I wrote code for sending mail to client from my company's domain. Now I want to track that,the mail is sent or not to the receiver. If mail is bounced I want that notification also. So what can I do for that?

```
  @Override
    public void sendEmail(EmailDTO emailDTO) throws EmailException {
        Session emailSession = authenticateMailServer();
        if (emailSession != null && StringUtils.isNotBlank(emailDTO.getEmailTo())) {
            try {
                Message message = new MimeMessage(emailSession);
                if (PMBSSubstypeConstants.CURRENT_SUBS_TYPE_ID <= 0) {
                    SubsType subsType = em.find(SubsType.class, 1);
                    SubsTypeUtils.setCurrentSubsType(subsType);
                }
                //if (StringUtils.isBlank(emailDTO.getEmailFrom())) {
                emailDTO.setEmailFrom(PMBSSubstypeConstants.MAIL_SERVER_EMAIL); //Fallback if from email is not received from UI
                //}
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(PMBSSubstypeConstants.MAIL_SERVER_EMAIL));//emailDTO.getEmailFrom()));
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(emailDTO.getEmailTo()));
                if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(emailDTO.getEmailCC())) {
                    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse(emailDTO.getEmailCC()));
                }
                if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(emailDTO.getEmailBCC())) {
                    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, InternetAddress.parse(emailDTO.getEmailBCC()));
                }
                message.setSubject(emailDTO.getEmailSubject());
                message.setContent(emailDTO.getEmailBody(), "text/html; charset=utf-8");
                if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(emailDTO.getReplayTO())) {
                    Address address[] = new Address[]{
                        new InternetAddress(emailDTO.getReplayTO())
                    };
                    message.setReplyTo(address);
                }
                Transport.send(message);

            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: *Bounced means in what sense ?* Wrong sender or wrong domain or something else ?

Comment: use the same API, check un read mails in inbox and analyse the content.

Comment: any kind of bounce it may be hard bounce or soft bounce

Comment: @ Vels4j I am not getting the same how should I can do can you please help me out